# JSLint Regexp Violation Quandry

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, jslint

I have the following regular expresssion

```
/\<oauth_token\>([^\<]*)\<\/oauth_token\>/
```

I am seeing jslint violations for unescaped < characters, but can't work out why.  Can anyone enlighten me please?

This regular expression is being assigned to a variable and is being used throughout the file.  It is in a nodejs module.

This is a hack to get round a non-standards conformant OAUth response, which will be fixed at some point in the future.  I do not want to bring in an XML parser as an extra dependency to solve the problem.

I am seeing this violation both with JSHint and node-jslint.

You can see the full source code for the file on [github](https://github.com/raoulmillais/node-7digital-api/blob/master/lib/oauth-helper.js)  The exact output from JSHint is as follows:

```
lib/oauth-helper.js: line 5, col 21, Unexpected escaped character '<' in regular expression.
lib/oauth-helper.js: line 5, col 39, Unexpected escaped character '<' in regular expression.
lib/oauth-helper.js: line 5, col 44, Unexpected escaped character '<' in regular expression.
lib/oauth-helper.js: line 6, col 22, Unexpected escaped character '<' in regular expression.
lib/oauth-helper.js: line 6, col 47, Unexpected escaped character '<' in regular expression.
lib/oauth-helper.js: line 6, col 52, Unexpected escaped character '<' in regular expression.
```

Comment: Is your script in a `<script>` tag?

Comment: It is in a nodejs module, I have updated the question

Comment: Does node.js not have an XML parser with which to extract the token value?

Comment: I'm sure it does, but this is the sole use case with known XML. I don't want to add an extra dependency, particularly since this is a hack to get round a non-standards conformant OAUth response, which will be fixed at some point in the future.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's no need to escape the "<" character in a regular expression.  That's what JSLint is telling you - that the backslashes before your "<" characters in the pattern are unnecessary.

Comment: D'oh.  Couldn't see the wood from the trees, should have re-read the message.  Thanks

Comment: Yes, +1 :) It`s also says to you:
"Unexpected escaped character '<' in regular expression."